# Getting multiple errors while compiling streamlit program

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, scipy, streamlit

While running this command:

```
streamlit run app.py
```

I am getting the following error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.integrate._ivp.common'`

I have installed all the required libraries for my programs.
Please guide me what should be the next step.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

```
pip install scipy
```

and then try running your `streamlit` app